# How to use itext-asian library in eclipse?

Tags: itext

**My Code:**

```
public static final String[] tempString = { "KozMinPro-Regular.otf", "UniJIS-UCS2-H", pharseString };
bf = BaseFont.createFont(tempString[0], tempString[1], BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

**Result:**

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: UniJIS-UCS2-H
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(PdfEncodings.java:186)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:376)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:705)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:621)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:456)
    at de.vogella.itext.write.Main.addTextJapanese(Main.java:145)
    at de.vogella.itext.write.Main.addContent(Main.java:134)
    at de.vogella.itext.write.Main.main(Main.java:254)
```

**My project:**

Please see link : http://upanh.in/Cmk

Do you have any suggestions how to fix bug that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blaming your tools for your own mistake.

This doesn't make sense:

```
public static final String[] tempString = { "KozMinPro-Regular.otf", "UniJIS-UCS2-H", pharseString };    
bf = BaseFont.createFont(tempString[0], tempString[1], BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

Either you have a font program named `KozMinPro-Regular.otf`, or you want to use the font `KozMinPro-Regular`.

If you have a file named `KozMinPro-Regular.otf`, you don't need the iText-Asian.jar. Just use the font file with an encoding that is supported by that font program. `UniJIS-UCS2-H` is not supported by that OpenType font.

If you want to use CJK fonts (the fonts that are not embedded and require a font pack in Adobe Reader), you should use `KozMinPro-Regular` (without the `otf`).

In short: you are confronted with a bug in **your** code, not with a bug in **the tools you are using**. You may want to phrase your questions differently in the future.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.
You said that"Just use the font file with an encoding that is supported by that font program.", then how to know what have encoding (KozMinPro-Regular.otf)?

Comment: See the `getCodePagesSupported()` method in the following example taken from in the documentation: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=197 (Also take a look at the other examples involving the `IDENTITY_H` encoding.)